# conditionally rendering className in react jsx

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
var array = [
  ['2','35'],
  ['80','30'],
  ['300','25']
]
```

so this is a simplified version of the array, what i am getting from an api call. Each children array's 1st value is **quantity** and 2nd value is **price**. below is my simplified state

```
this.state = {quantity:''}
```

Inside jsx what i am trying to do is conditionally render a classname called **selected** based upon **quantity** value of the state. whenever the state **quantity** changes. the **selected** class also should change accordingly.
below is my jsx

```
{array.map((price, index, arr) => {
  if (index < arr.length -1) {
      if (parseInt(arr[index+1][0]) > parseInt(this.state.quantity) && parseInt(this.state.quantity) >= parseInt(price[0])){
          return (
            <div className='price-box selected'>
              <h3 className='price'>Tk {price[1]}</h3>
              <p className='quantity'>{price[0]} or more</p>
            </div>
          );
      } else {
          return (
            <div className='price-box'>
              <h3 className='price'>Tk {price[1]}</h3>
              <p className='quantity'>{price[0]} or more</p>
            </div>
          );
      }
  } else {
      if (parseInt(this.state.quantity) >= parseInt(price[0])) {
          return (
            <div className='price-box selected'>
              <h3 className='price'>Tk {price[1]}</h3>
              <p className='quantity'>{price[0]} or more</p>
            </div>
          );
      } else {
          return (
            <div className='price-box'>
              <h3 className='price'>Tk {price[1]}</h3>
              <p className='quantity'>{price[0]} or more</p>
            </div>
          );
      }
  }      
})}
```

Here everything is working fine (apart from for quantity 0 and 1 all of the conditions are evaluating to false as expected.so not a single div is assigned selected class).I am 100% sure there is a shorter and better approach.

Comment: Have you checked-out [`clsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)? You could also determine the class name ahead of the rendering and pass that in as a bound reference.

Comment: Do you need to show selected when your quantity (left on the array) equals the selected ?

Comment: I need to show selected when the state quantity is equals to the quantity(left on the array) or in the range. Here is what i want
as i am maping over an array of 3 elements(array).so there is basically three div
if quantity(state) is from 0-79 assign the selected class to the first div. 
if quantity(state) is from 80-299 assign the selected class to the second div. 
if quantity(state) is from 300 to above assign the selected class to the third div.

Comment: going based on quantity value is very wrong, you could end up with two diffrent array with the same quantity and that will create a problem. You should go after selected index instead. I could make an answer but i saw you already accepted @lawrence-witt answer.

Comment: As for my apps qunatity is always going to be unique. Here is the real life scenario if you buy (2-79) pairs of shoes, you have to pay 35$/each pair. if you buy (80-299) pairs, you'll pay 30$/each pair and so on. So for my use case if quantity is same the price also remains same. so there is no different array for same quantity of an individual product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your data points and construct a test which satisfies all the requirements for `selected`. Then assign the class name if `selected` is true using a template literal.

```
{array.map((price, index, arr) => {
  const stateQ = parseInt(this.state.quantity);
  const dataQs = arr.map((p, i) => i === 0 ? 0 : parseInt(p[0]));
  
  const selectedIndex = dataQs.findIndex((q, i, arr) => {
    return stateQ >= q && stateQ < (arr[i+1] || stateQ + 1);
  });
  const selected = selectedIndex === index;
  
  return (
    <div className={`price-box ${selected && 'selected'}`}>
      <h3 className='price'>Tk {price[1]}</h3>
      <p className='quantity'>{price[0]} or more</p>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.that's a very nice way of coding. Still for quantity(state) 0 and 1 that doesn't solve. in my condition i excluded 0 and 1. but what i want is when quantity is from 0-79.(not from 2-79 as my condition) first div should be assigned selected class.

Comment: I think I've understood what you're after and added a revision - let me know if that's right and I'll remove the original snippet. The new one works by getting an array of quantities (adjusted to 0 for index 0), and finding the index of the quantitiy that is less than the state quantity and followed by one of greater quantity (with an escape of `stateQ + 1` if its the last in the array). It relies on the input array being properly sorted by quantity so if that's not guaranteed you might need to sort `arr` before mapping in `dataQs`.

Comment: Yeah. Now woking perfectly fine. Alreay using your code snippet in my project. Though to be honest i still didn't get the const selectedIndex part. For example if stateQ = 80 . And inside dataQs.findIndex i am in my first iteration. then 80>0 && 80 <(80 || 81) evaluates to true. Shouldn't the selectedIndex value be 0(as my  first iteration evaluates to true). so const selected is also assigned true at index 0. so the first div of the three div should be assinged selected class? why here things happening differently? what am i missing?

Comment: There is a subtle difference between `(80 < 80 || 80 < 81)` and `80 < (80 || 81)`. Anything inside parentheses gets evaluated first and separately - the expression `(80 || 81)` evaluates whether the elements are truthy, which they both are, so it will always resolve to just `80 < 80`. When `arr[i+1]` goes beyond the length of the array it is `undefined`, so it falls back to `stateQ + 1` instead. I agree its not the cleanest solution and there will be a better way to write a separate function to handle range look ups like this but that's probably beyond the scope of this question!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for ?

[Working example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-cookies-n8cbm?file=/src/App.js)

```
class Quantity extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quantity: "2"
    };
  }

  render() {
    const array = [["2", "35"], ["80", "30"], ["300", "25"], ["2"], ["", "3"]]; // With some errors
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        {array.map((row) => {
          const condition = this.state.quantity === row[0]; // Create your condition
          if (row && row[0] && row[1])
            return (
              <div className={`price-box ${condition && "selected"}`}> // Called template literal, you can simply include selected if your condition is true
                <h3>Quantity {row[0]}</h3>
                <p>Price {row[1]}</p>
              </div>
            );
          else return <div>Data error</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```